# Error ORA-01779 al actualizar campo

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy actualizando un campo de una tabla A con el valor de otra tabla B, al actualizar me genera el siguiente error, alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo?

> ORA-01779: no se puede modificar una columna que se corresponde con una tabla no reservada por clave

```
> UPDATE (SELECT AA.PLAZA, BB.NOM
>     FROM TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD_PSTVS AA 
>     INNER JOIN TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD2_TEST BB 
>         ON AA.SEQ=BB.SEQ
>      WHERE AA.SEQ='696202662' AND AA.PLAZA IS NULL  ) t SET t.PLAZA    = t.NOM;
```

Comment: necesitas si o si el join, no podes ir a hacer la busqueda por cada registro (tipo a.plaza = (select de la otra tabla)... digo, porque probablemente (habria que ver tu oracle) pero esto estaria bloqueado porque estas tratando de actualizar tablas vivas sin restringir las mismas....

Answer (score 2):

Estas armando una subquery compleja para hacer update, te aconsejaría simplificarla porque el optimizador de Oracle te va a tirar este error en la mayoría de los casos. Probaría algo como esto:

```
UPDATE TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD_PSTVS P
SET P.PLAZA = (SELECT T.NOM FROM TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD2_TEST T WHERE P.SEQ=P.SEQ)
WHERE P.SEQ='696202662' AND P.PLAZA IS NULL
```

Comment: en esta subquery SELECT T.NOM FROM TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD2_TEST T WHERE P.SEQ=P.SEQ  en la condicion, es: P.SEQ=P.SEQ  o T.SEQ=P.SEQ?

Comment: me aparece un mensaje: ORA-01427: la subconsulta de una sola fila devuelve más de una fila, sabes como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Quizás ese es el problema. Cuando hacías tu `UPDATE` original Oracle se daba cuenta de que había varias filas entonces no sabe de cuál tomar el valor para asignar al destino

Answer (score 0):

No es precisamente tu caso. Pero yo lo solucioné cuando cambié el LEFT JOIN por el INNER JOIN. De esa manera Oracle no se queja de que pueden existir valores que no se correspondan. Quizás a alguien le sirva